# After I installed anaconda, pip installation now gives "ssl module in Python is not available" error. How to fix this without uninstalling anaconda?

Tags: python, openssl, pycharm, anaconda, windows-10

I've been enrolling in JetBrains academy for almost 2 months now to learn python core and machine learning with python. I have learned how to create new virtual environments using PyCharm IDE and use pip installation to install useful packages. At some point when I was ready to learn the Machine Learning track, it was recommended to install anaconda navigator since it provides tonnes of pre-installed packages that are helpful for machine learning tasks.

> ###### PROBLEM:
>
> However, ever since I downloaded anaconda navigator, I could use pip installation in conda environment ONLY. In other virtual environments, the following error occurs: `"...pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available"`.
>
> ###### SUGGESTED SOLUTIONS FOUND:
>
> Some solution suggested that I should uninstall anaconda and python,
> then re-install python to fix this. However, this method would defeat
> my purpose of installing anaconda in the first place.
>
> ###### MY QUESTION:
>
> How to fix this error without uninstalling anaconda?

Followings are my configurations:

- *PyCharm Community Edition 2022.1.1 on Windows 10*
- *Python 3.9.10 running in a Virtual Environment (e.g. Virtualenv)*
- *anaconda navigator 2.2.0*
- *anaconda3 with openssl 1.1.1n and pyopenssl 21.0.0 modules installed*

Answer (score 0):

I actually got some idea from this [link](https://exerror.com/pip-is-configured-with-locations-that-require-tls-ssl-however-the-ssl-module-in-python-is-not-available/#:%7E:text=not%20available%20Error%20%3F-,To%20Solve%20pip%20is%20configured%20with%20locations%20that%20require%20TLS,Edit%20Path%20variable.). The author added extra paths for anaconda folders with openssl into the python interpreter paths:

In the PyCharm IDE, I fixed the error with the following steps:

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| 1. | Go to: Settings -> Project -> Python interpreter |
| 2. | Click on the "gear symbol" and select "Show All...". This will navigate you to a "Python Interpreters" window. |
| 3. | While your intended interpreter is highlighted, click on the "path symbol" which will navigate you to an "Interpreter Paths" window. |
| 4. | Click "+" symbol to add path in the interpreter paths window. |
| 5. | Add a new interpreter path as shown below. (Type `where conda` in anaconda prompt to find the full path to anaconda3 folder) |
| 6. | In my case, I needed to restart my PyCharm IDE for the pip installation to finally work. |

```
<my full path to anaconda3>
<my full path to anaconda3>\Scripts
<my full path to anaconda3>\Library\bin
```

> ###### NOTES:
>
> I still wonder if this is the best method there is or is there a way to install the openssl directly into my virtual environment without redirecting my interpreter paths to the ones in anaconda folder.